# Unable to start appium server programmatically. Error: spawn ENOTDIR

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I am trying to launch appium server using 'AppiumServiceBuilder' in mac. I am referring the following website:

https://appiumpro.com/editions/71

I am using the following code:

```
AppiumServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
serviceBuilder.usingAnyFreePort();
serviceBuilder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"));
serviceBuilder.withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/bin/appium"));
HashMap<String, String> environment = new HashMap();
environment.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin/carthage"); 
serviceBuilder.withEnvironment(environment);
server = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(TLDriverFactory.serviceBuilder);
server.start();
```

while starting the appium am using this:

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","12.3.1");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
capabilities.setCapability("udid", getDeviceID());
capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", getBundleId());
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
capabilities.setCapability("waitForQuiescence", false);
capabilities.setCapability("useJSONSource", true);      
iDriver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(server.getUrl(),capabilities);
```

This is the console message am getting during the iDriver initialization:

```
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"desiredCapabilities":{"waitForQuiescence":false,"noReset":true,"useJSONSource":true,"platformVersion":"12.3.1","automationName":"XCUITest","bundleId":"com.tekion.cdmsmobileenterprise","platformName":"iOS","udid":"cc6080c50dad4605d8e5511e89410792f0100026","deviceName":"iPhone 6"},"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:bundleId":"com.tekion.cdmsmobileenterprise","appium:deviceName":"iPhone 6","appium:noReset":true,"platformName":"ios","appium:platformVersion":"12.3.1","appium:udid":"cc6080c50dad4605d8e5511e89410792f0100026","useJSONSource":true,"waitForQuiescence":false},"firstMatch":[{}]}}[39m
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"waitForQuiescence":false,"noReset":true,"useJSONSource":true,"platformVersion":"12.3.1","automationName":"XCUITest","bundleId":"com.tekion.cdmsmobileenterprise","platformName":"iOS","udid":"cc6080c50dad4605d8e5511e89410792f0100026","deviceName":"iPhone 6"},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:bundleId":"com.tekion.cdmsmobileenterprise","appium:deviceName":"iPhone 6","appium:noReset":true,"platformName":"ios","appium:platformVersion":"12.3.1","appium:udid":"cc6080c50dad4605d8e5511e89410792f0100026","useJSONSource":true,"waitForQuiescence":false},"firstMatch":[{}]}]
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1568395822117 (23:00:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[35m[BaseDriver][39m The capabilities ["useJSONSource","waitForQuiescence"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix
[35m[Appium][39m Appium v1.13.0 creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.113.2) session
[35m[Appium][39m Capabilities:
[35m[Appium][39m   platformName: ios
[35m[Appium][39m   useJSONSource: true
[35m[Appium][39m   waitForQuiescence: false
[35m[Appium][39m   automationName: XCUITest
[35m[Appium][39m   bundleId: com.tekion.cdmsmobileenterprise
[35m[Appium][39m   deviceName: iPhone 6
[35m[Appium][39m   noReset: true
[35m[Appium][39m   platformVersion: 12.3.1
[35m[Appium][39m   udid: cc6080c50dad4605d8e5511e89410792f0100026
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"waitForQuiescence":false,... were provided
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa...
[35m[BaseDriver][39m Session created with session id: 7e5f96b0-2540-41d4-9d2f-4153ffef9cd3
[debug] [35m[XCUITest][39m Unable to get username running server: spawn ENOTDIR
[35m[XCUITest][39m Error: spawn ENOTDIR
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:394:11)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at spawn (child_process.js:540:9)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:30:16
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at Promise.cancellationExecute [as _execute] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:335:9)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at new Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:27:10)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at getConnectedDevices (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/real-device-management.js:8:26)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at XCUITestDriver.determineDevice (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:762:31)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at XCUITestDriver.determineDevice [as start] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:269:51)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:58:5)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:412:9)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at XCUITestDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:206:7)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:342:35)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:319:13)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:471:14)
[35m[XCUITest][39m     at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:352:21)
[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1568395822141 (23:00:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m Encountered internal error running command: Error: spawn ENOTDIR
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:394:11)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at spawn (child_process.js:540:9)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:30:16
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at Promise.cancellationExecute [as _execute] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:335:9)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at new Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:27:10)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at getConnectedDevices (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/real-device-management.js:8:26)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at XCUITestDriver.determineDevice (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:762:31)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at XCUITestDriver.determineDevice [as start] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:269:51)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:58:5)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:412:9)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at XCUITestDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:206:7)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AppiumDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:342:35)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:319:13)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:471:14)
[debug] [35m[W3C][39m     at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:352:21)
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[31m500[39m [90m28 ms - 523[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Abduls-MacBook-Pro-2.local', ip: '2402:3a80:464:2a24:6980:fa71:954a:5c2b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '12'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:95)
    at com.utilities.TLDriverFactory.initializeIOSDriver(TLDriverFactory.java:225)
    at com.utilities.TLDriverFactory.setTLDriver(TLDriverFactory.java:134)
    at com.utilities.Tek_Properties.beforeMethodReporting(Tek_Properties.java:257)
    at com.utilities.Mobile_TestBase.initializWebDriver(Mobile_TestBase.java:162)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:185)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: spawn ENOTDIR
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Abduls-MacBook-Pro-2.local', ip: '2402:3a80:464:2a24:6980:fa71:954a:5c2b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '12'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:826:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:447:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 49 more
```

I [googled](https://discuss.appium.io/t/unable-to-get-username-running-server-spawn-enotdir/25713) and found that the spawn : enotdir is due to missing phantomJS. I did it:

```
brew cask install phantomjs
node rebuild
```

I am still getting the issue.

I have two questions:
1. How to resolve this issue and make it work?
2. While launching iDriver, why it says 'The capabilities ["useJSONSource","waitForQuiescence"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix'? Does that mean these capabilities won't work if appium is launched via AppiumServiceBuilder?

Mac version: macOS Mojave 10.14.6 
Appium Version: 1.13.0 
Appium Java Client: 6.1.0 (Tried with 7.2.0 as well) 
Selenium Version: 3.4.0

Comment: I have also tried to launch the appium server from terminal.
I have created a file - appiumSh.command with following lines:
`#!/bin/bash 
/usr/local/bin/appium`

When I try to call the file from program it is not working:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cwd + "/appiumSh.command")`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this code:

```
AppiumServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
serviceBuilder.usingAnyFreePort();
serviceBuilder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"));
serviceBuilder.withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/bin/appium"));
HashMap<String, String> environment = new HashMap();
environment.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH"));
serviceBuilder.withEnvironment(environment);        

server.set(AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(serviceBuilder));
server.get().start();
```

This worked fine for me.